# how to add space between two columns in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have made form in contact form 7, and i have used Column Shortcodes plugin that form should have two fields in one row, its worked but where do i add some space between two fields in one row 
I have tried this `.wpcf7 p {margin-right:10px;}` but it does not take effect

here is the link to site
https://www.childrensdentalclinicjonesboro.com/admission/

I expect that the each fields should have little space between them, but its does not have

Comment: Quick fix for you might be to add this custom CSS: `.wpcf7-form .last_column p {padding-left:10px;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this CSS for below result

```
.one_half { width: 47.5% !important;
margin-right: 2.5% !important;}
```

[image]

Comment: **My Pleasure friend!**